# Guava 18 does not compile with GWT 2.8Snapshot and Java 8

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, java-8, guava

I use  in my gwt.xml module and put

```
guava-18.0.jar
guava-gwt-18.0.jar

   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.common.collect.Collections2'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java'
         [ERROR] Line 201: The method and(Predicate<capture#14-of ? super E>, Predicate<capture#15-of ?>) is undefined for the type Collections2.FilteredCollection<E>
         [ERROR] Line 206: The method and(Predicate<capture#16-of ? super E>, Predicate<capture#17-of ?>) is undefined for the type Collections2.FilteredCollection<E>
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.common.collect.Maps'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/Maps.java'
         [ERROR] Line 2244: The method and(Predicate<capture#263-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>, Predicate<capture#264-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>) is undefined for the type Predicates
         [ERROR] Line 2343: The method and(Predicate<capture#265-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>, Predicate<capture#266-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>) is undefined for the type Predicates
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.common.collect.Multimaps'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/common/collect/super/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.java'
         [ERROR] Line 1691: The method and(Predicate<capture#83-of ? super K>, Predicate<capture#84-of ? super K>) is undefined for the type Predicates
         [ERROR] Line 1954: The method and(Predicate<capture#105-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>, Predicate<capture#106-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>) is undefined for the type Predicates
         [ERROR] Line 1735: The method and(Predicate<capture#87-of ? super K>, Predicate<capture#88-of ? super K>) is undefined for the type Predicates
         [ERROR] Line 1779: The method and(Predicate<capture#91-of ? super K>, Predicate<capture#92-of ? super K>) is undefined for the type Predicates
         [ERROR] Line 1940: The method and(Predicate<capture#103-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>, Predicate<capture#104-of ? super Map.Entry<K,V>>) is undefined for the type Predicates
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

Edit: There is a discussion in the google GWT-Contributors group her: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit-contributors/zYUfanL8zwM

Here is an issue for this problem: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9036

**Is there a workaround for this problem?**

Edit: I tested with the Guava 19SNAPSHOT and got the same error.

Comment: Afaik GWT 2.7 does not support Java 8 (but I'm not sure if your problem is caused by this).

Comment: I am using the 2.8 Snapshot.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=9036) with GWT and the version of JDT it's using.

The fix given in the bug report is to upgrade the jdt version, run update-jdt.py, and update dev/build.xml to point to the new version.

Alternatively, you can try different versions of guava, or start removing the methods/classes from guava that don't work.

Or you can wait until a newer version of gwt is released which will fix these issues.

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail how this is done? Where do I find the update-jdt.py file? What do I have to change in dev/build.xml and where do I have to put the jar file with the jdt fix?

Comment: The issue is now "FixedNotReleased" so a recent snapshot should already contain the fix.